# движение объекта к заданной точке

Tags: java

я делаю игру на java похожую на браузерную игру [agar.io](http://agar.io) управление шариком происходит с помощью мышки то есть пользователь кликает на карту и шарик должен идти в эту точку я уже примерно понял как это делается вот код:

```
javax.swing.Timer move = new javax.swing.Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            x += vx / 10;
            y += vy / 10;
        }
    });
```

в данном случае я использую таймер для движения, я считаю это самым лучшим способом. но есть одна проблема, шарик движется в нужную сторону но как бы далеко или близко не была точка шарик доходит до неё с одинаковым временем мне надо решить эту проблему. могу предложить способ решения с помощью

```
Math.atan2()
и
Math.sin()/Math.cos()
```

Comment: А вам нужно, чтоб скорость не зависела от расстояния? Если есть решение, то в чем проблема?

Comment: @RomanKonoval мне надо чтобы шарик доходил до точки с одной скоростью и решения нет

Comment: Что тогда значит "могу предложить способ решения с помощью"?

Comment: проблему я решил а это значит что прошу найти способ с использованием этого

Answer (score 1, accepted):

к `x` прибавляем `Math.sin(Math.atan2(dx, dy)) * 2`
а к `y` прибавляем `Math.cos(Math.atan2(dx, dy)) * 2`